# Error while building oozie 4.1.0 using command mkdistro

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

i have been trying to configure and setup an oozie environment in my hadoop cluster.

system information

```
jdk 1.8
hadoop 2.4
maven 3.3.0
oozie 4.1.0
```

following this particular [post from quora](https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-tried-installing-oozie-4-0-0-with-apache-hadoop-2-2-0-and-java1-7-0_45-on-ubuntu).

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.oozie:oozie-zookeeper-security-tests:4.1.0 (/usr/local/oozie_4.1.0/oozie/zookeeper-security-tests/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:jar:2.4.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:pom:2.4.0 from/to repository.cloudera.com (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local): repository.cloudera.com: unknown error: Unknown host repository.cloudera.com: unknown error -> [Help 2]
```

now i tried changing my oozie version to 4.0.1 and i get the below error now.

[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin' from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), repository.cloudera.com (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]

kindly help me resolve this. thanks in adv :)

Comment: request any expert to help me on this.. i am stuck and not able to proceed due to this error

Comment: now after switching to 4.0.1 i am getting error like  below 





[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-clover2-plugin' from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), repository.cloudera.com (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/ext-release-local), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the pluginrepository to maven central?

replace the `<pluginrepository>` part in the pom.xml to

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: thanks for this input that really helped . now i am getting some other error like below

error :

ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'assembly' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]